# What do I need to do in order to use Enigmail on more than one PC?

Tags: encryption, email, enigmail

I've already imported my keys from pc1 to pc2, but on pc2 I always get this error message:

```
Error - no matching private/secret key found to decrypt message; 
click on 'Details' button for more information
```

I'm rather new to Enigmail, but from what I know about asynchronous encryption, having my private key should be enough to decrypt the message, no? What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that on pc1 you exported both your public and private keys, and not just your public key alone?

Comment: https://enigmail.wiki/Key_Management#Making_a_backup_of_your_key_pair This is how I did it, I did specifically export the private/secret key as well.